# Converting file from Unix to Windows / DOS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, dos

I have several files generated from UNIX with values like

```
1 TEST1
2 TEST2
3 TEST3
4 TEST4
5 TEST5
6 TEST6
```

I tried to copy the file to sharing folder, try to download it to my local pc (Windows 10) and opened it and worked fine.
But after, i open the file on my Aplication server (Windows Server 2012R2), the file value became

```
1TEST12TEST23TEST34TEST45TEST56TEST6
```

I've already tried with

- sed -i 's/\r$//g'
- sed 's/$'"/`echo \\\r`/" filename.txt > filename.txt
- perl
- awk
  but none of them work

Comment: You can have a look at the utility `unix2dos`, that will do the exact opposite of `dos2unix`

Comment: @smoldev : Of course `unix2dos` will, as Aserre noted, put in those silly carriage returns you want to have, but first of all, why do you **need** them. Nowadays, the vast majority of Windoze applications can happily process a lone linefeed as a line terminator. In your posting, you mention that you want to _*open*_ the file on Windows. What **exactly** do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look at:

```
sed -r -i 's:\r$:\r\n:g' your-file-name.txt
```

Comment: i tried with sed -r -i 's:\r$:\r\n:g' your-file-name.txt
and in my notepad it still open like before,
but when i opened it with another text editor (wordpad) its already show like what i wanted.

i have suspect on notepad that installed on my pc server